# Quick Launch Flyout Menu

Tags: navigation

How would I go about creating a flyout menu from the quick launch sidebar?

This is what I am using in my master page:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
```

Ideally I need the headings to stay static and then when I hover over a link, a menu will pop out to the right. I've tried creating subsites, but I can only get the drop-down menu to work from the Global Navigation. Is there any way to create this type of flyout?

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels`?

Comment: Yep, I tried all sorts of combinations with MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels and StaticDisplayLevels. I noticed in 'All Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation' I have a few radio options grayed out. One of them looks like it could help me fix my issue with allowing subsites to display a submenu. I believe it says 'Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings.' Is there a way to allow this option?

Comment: They are grayed out because it displays them by default when you change the value of `StaticDisplayLevels` and `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels`. How you configure the Navigation for the subsites determines what gets displayed.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know why this isn't working then. I tried setting StaticDisplayLevels to 1 and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels to 4, but even still I was unable to get the flyout menus for subsites. They flyout menus for the regular headings worked fine however.